# Plug multiple people into a large data set

Tags: sql, bigdata, powerbi, tableau-api

I have a fairly large sql server data set that I need to plug multiple people into to view and export data. I need to only allow a user to see their filtered data and not see everyone else's data. Power bi is a great tool along with tableau but it feels painful to implement for over 100 users when that individual user should only see their data. Is there a better way to go about serving the data up?

Comment: Depending on how you 'filter for their data' Tableau has the ability to access the userid if they are on the server and you could use this in a filter condition for the dashboard.

Comment: Read about “user filters” in the online help for Tableau

Comment: And in SQL Server and Power BI you can use Row-Level Security.

Comment: This is great, row level security I think would solve my issue. Thanks for the feedback!